# Haskell - foldl $ lambda Set.empty

Tags: haskell, lambda

I guess there is something wrong in this example (from the [book's chapter](http://nlpwp.org/book/chap-words.xhtml#sec-words-playwords)) or I miss something:

```
Prelude> let wordSet = foldl (\s e -> Data.Set.insert e s) Data.Set.empty
```

Then:

`Prelude> wordSet ["blue", "blue", "red", "blue", "red"]`

will not work. It will fail with an error:

> Couldn't match expected type '()' with actual type `[Char]'

Seems `wordSet` function has no any expecting parameter to pass?

And still don't get why `Data.Set.empty` is the second param of `foldl` but not first. And how are we supposed to pass stuff into the `wordSet`.

Q: how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Are you sure you entered this correctly? It does work fine for me. The type of foldl is `(b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` by the way, so Data.Set.empty is the starting value. The third argument is where the data goes?

Comment: Ignore that, it seems NoMonomorphismRestriction is default in my ghc version.

Comment: Aʟᴡᴀʏꜱ use type signatures!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is another case of the dreaded [**monomorphism restriction**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

There are several ways to circumvent this:

#### add the *point*

```
let wordSet ws = foldl (\s e -> Data.Set.insert e s) Data.Set.empty ws
```

#### disable the restriction

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let wordSet = foldl (\s e -> Data.Set.insert e s) Data.Set.empty
> :t wordSet
wordSet :: Ord a => [a] -> containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Set.Base.Set a
```

#### add type-signatures inside GHCi (thank you @Zeta)

```
let{ wordSet :: Ord e => [e] -> Data.Set.Set e; wordSet = foldl (\s e -> Data.Set.insert e s) Data.Set.empty}
```

#### use and load a source file (with type-signatures)

```
module WordSet where

import Data.Set (Set, insert, empty)

wordSet :: (Ord e) => [e] -> Set e
wordSet = foldl (\s e -> insert e s) empty
```

#### use and load a source file (disable the restriction)

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module WordSet where

import Data.Set (Set, insert, empty)

wordSet = foldl (\s e -> insert e s) empty
```

**please note:** this one is not-idiomatic as you should give signatures to your top-level definitions (GHC will most likely warn you).

Comment: Or your last variant in GHCi, either in multiline mode (`:{`->`:}` or `:+m`) or without layout: `let{ wordSet :: Ord e => [e] -> Set e; wordSet = foldl (\s e -> insert e s) empty}`

Comment: Thank you - I'll gonna include it

Comment: @Zeta: You don't even need the braces, a simple `let f :: stuff; f = ...` also works